# Listen to Changes on an Object's field in Angular2/Typescript

Tags: typescript, angular, observable

In Angular2/Typescript, is it possible to "observe" an object's field for changes.

For example, say I have a class `Person` with fields `firstName`, `lastName`, and `fullName`. Is it possible to automatically update `fullName` whenever either `firstName` or `lastName` changes?

Something like this:

```
export class Person {
  firstName: string= '';
  lastName: string = '';
  fullName: string = '';

  constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
    this.firstName.onChange(() => { this.updateFullName(); });
    this.lastName.onChange(() => { this.updateFullName(); });

    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  updateFullName() {
    this.fullName = `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**First approach**

You could leverage TypeScript setters / getters as described below to synchronize fullName with firstName and lastName:

```
get lastName() {
  return this._lastName;
}

set lastName(lastName:string) {
  this._lastName = lastName;
  this.fullName = this._firstName + ' ' + this._lastName;
}

get firstName() {
  return this._firstName;
}

set firstName(firstName:string) {
  this._firstName = firstName;
  this.fullName = this._firstName + ' ' + this._lastName;
}
```

This way when setting lastName or firstName, fullName is automatically updated:

```
var p = new Person();
p.lastName = 'last';
p.firstName = 'first';
console.log(p.fullName); // print 'first last'
```

**Second approach**

Angular2 by default doesn't allow to define change of properties within objects. It only detects updates of at references. I mean if the reference (or value for primitive types) of a bound property is updated.

That bien said, Angular2 allows to plugin your own strategy using the ngDoCheck hook method.

In it you can leverage the KeyValueDiffers class (to be injected) to detect updates in specific objects.

See this link for more details:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DoCheck-interface.html

Here is a sample:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  (...)
}) 
export class MyComponent implements DoCheck {
  @Input() person: Person;
  differ: any;

  constructor(differs:  KeyValueDiffers) {
    this.differ = differs.find([]).create(null);
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    var changes = this.differ.diff(this.person);

    if (changes) {
      changes.forEachChangedItem((elt) => {
        if (elt.key === 'firstName' || elt.key === 'lastName' ) {
          this.person.fullName = this.person.firstName + ' ' + this.person.lastName;
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

When the value of the `prop1` property is updated, the `doSomethingIfProp1Change` method is called.

See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/uvOKMXQa9Ik8EiIhb60Y?p=preview.

Comment: Yep, thanks!

Is the second solution the only way to listen to changes in an array, btw?

Comment: Great! Yes for changes within arrays and objects, it's the only way in Angular2. For example ngFor and ngClass rely on this mechanism ;-) ngOnChanges doesn't apply in this case...

Comment: It seems this is no longer the case with latest angular version. I am seeing ngDoCheck get trigger after a considerable lag on update